# Discord.JS v13 API Errors every time I send an embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Whenever I try send an embed using slash commands in my bot, I get a DiscordAPIError, which looks something like this:

```
/home/runner/TFOBOT/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/TFOBOT/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/TFOBOT/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async CommandInteraction.reply (/home/runner/TFOBOT/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:99:5) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/interactions/937065446656577627/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246OTM3MDY1NDQ2NjU2NTc3NjI3Ok5wSVRGNzlBZkJ6YURJNWtqR29tMmdLd1FpRUpXQVEySHRTZmlPa1d1elpWbG5XOUJudkNubDNlMmc4WnM2bDZFOUhiTm9TOXJMaDJmYVpOUFd2WmJQUnl2d0tkVEs1dDJoNHV2VmJhTElsZUhWbGNyd3FoOTNTTGp1NGZKTFZ5/callback',
  code: 10062,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      type: 4,
      data: {
        content: undefined,
        tts: false,
        nonce: undefined,
        embeds: [
          {
            title: 'XP for MystX2',
            type: 'rich',
            description: null,
            url: null,
            timestamp: 2022-01-29T19:23:50.855Z,
            color: 3447003,
            fields: [Array],
            thumbnail: [Object],
            image: null,
            author: null,
            footer: [Object]
          }
        ],
        components: undefined,
        username: undefined,
        avatar_url: undefined,
        allowed_mentions: undefined,
        flags: undefined,
        message_reference: undefined,
        attachments: undefined,
        sticker_ids: undefined
      }
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

I only ever get these errors when attempting to reply to an interaction with an embed, any ideas on how to fix? It appears to me that the interaction cannot be found, however, it always works without fail if I do not include an embed, and just regular text instead.

For reference, this is the code which is causing the errors:

```
interaction.reply({ embeds:[xpEmbed] })
```

Comment: Maybe you are too slow? You have to respond within 3 seconds, otherwise the reply gate is closed and the interaction no longer exists for you to respond to. I'm guessing whatever you do to get the embed in the first place is what's causing this as it takes too long, not the fact itself that you are sending an embed. (Or maybe you are attempting to send a reply twice to the same interaction, that would also give you this error on the second reply.)

Comment: See [docs](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/replying-to-slash-commands.html#responding-to-a-command). If you need more time, you have to use a [deferred response](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/replying-to-slash-commands.html#deferred-responses).

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for your response, I think this is the issue